# How to Check if a RE In Python was Performed

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if a regular expression was executed on a specific line of the opened document and then if so add to
a count variable by 1. If the count exceeds 2 I want it to stop. The below code is what I have so far.

```
for line in book:
    if count<=2:
            reg1 = re.sub(r'Some RE',r'Replaced with..',line)
            f.write(reg1)
            "if reg1 was Performed add to count variable by 1"
```

Answer (score 4):

Definitely the best way of doing this is to use [`re.subn()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.subn) instead `re.sub()`

The `re.subn()` returns a tuple `(new_string, number_of_changes_made)` so it's perfect for you:

```
for line in book:
    if count<=2:
        reg1, num_of_changes = re.subn(r'Some RE',r'Replaced with..',line)
        f.write(reg1)
        if num_of_changes > 0:
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If the idea is to determine if a substitution was performed on the line, it is fairly simple:

```
count = 0
for line in book:
    if count<=2:
        reg1 = re.sub(r'Some RE',r'Replaced with..',line)
        f.write(reg1)
        count += int(reg1 == line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to `re.sub` as the replacement value.  This lets you do stuff like this: (though a simple search then sub approach while slower would be easier to reason about):

```
import re

class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.value = start

    def incr(self):
        self.value += 1

book = """This is some long text
with the text 'Some RE' appearing twice:
Some RE see?
"""

def countRepl(replacement, counter):
    def replacer(matchobject):
        counter.incr()
        return replacement

    return replacer

counter = Counter(0)

print re.sub(r'Some RE', countRepl('Replaced with..', counter), book)

print counter.value
```

This produces the following output:

```
This is some long text
with the text 'Replaced with..' appearing twice:
Replaced with.. see?

2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare it to the original string to see if it changed:

```
for line in book:
    if count<=2:
        reg1 = re.sub(r'Some RE',r'Replaced with..',line)
        f.write(reg1)
        if line != reg1:
            count += 1
```

Comment: And what would the if statement look like if it wasn't performed on that line?

Comment: ... the opposite of `!=` (not equal) is what? `==` (equal) of course.

Comment: It just wouldn't increment the counter, because `line` and `reg1` would be the same. `re.sub()` just returns the original string if there was no match.

Answer (score 0):

subn will tell you how many substitutions were made in the line and the count parameter will limit the number of substitutions that will be attempted. Put them together and you have code that will stop after two substitutions, even if there are multiple subs on a single line.

```
look_count = 2
for line in book:
    reg1, sub_count = re.subn(r'Some RE', r'Replaced with..', line,count=look_count)
    f.write(reg1)
    look_count -= sub_count
    if not look_count:
        break
```